# How do I use the pandas.melt function to unpivot a few columns while keeping the rest intact

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a database with 66 columns and I wish to unpivot only 3 columns using python `pandas.melt` function.

```
df = pd.melt(df,value_vars=["RFR 1","RFR 2","RFR 3"],var_name="RFR Index",value_name="RFR Mode")
```

I'm finding all the other columns are dropped unless I set them as `id_vars`. How do I keep them all without listing all of them? (since there are so many of them)

Comment: There is no need for sample code or expected output here, the question is generic enough and clear enough to be answered without either of these.  Adding the sample data doesn't add anything to the context or the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pandas.Index.difference` to get all columns of your dataframe that are not in your specified list.

A bit of a nonsensical example, but:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(5,10),
                  columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'])

val_vars = ['e','f','g']
other_vars = df.columns.difference(val_vars)

df.melt(id_vars=other_vars, value_vars=val_vars)
```

An alternative approach not using pandas-specific functionality would be to use sets:

`other_vars = set(df.columns) - set(val_vars)`

Answer (score 1):

Just create list that doesn't include the columns that are in the `value_vars`

```
value_vars = ["RFR 1","RFR 2","RFR 3"]
id_vars = [x for x in df.columns if x not in value_vars]
df = pd.melt(df,value_vars=value_vars,var_name="RFR Index",value_name="RFR Mode", id_vars=id_vars)
```

Comment: This was very helpful as well. Thanks!